# Check internet availability before sending the data to database

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am new to Python 2.7. I am writing a program where I need to check the availability of internet for my Wifi (sometimes the internet disconnects) before I proceed to send the data to the database using the Internet. The send data to database will be skipped if there is no internet connection. How can I do that. Is this the correct way that I doing this?

```
import urllib                                                        
#Perhaps check internet availability first                               
try:
    import httplib
except:
    import http.client as httplib

def have_internet():
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection("www.google.com", timeout=5)
    try:
        conn.request("HEAD", "/")
        conn.close()
        return True
    except:
        conn.close()
        return False


#send data to database
data = {'date':date_mmddyyyy,'time':time_hhmmss,'airtemperature':temperature_c,'humidity':humidity_c, 'watertemperature':watertemp_c, 'phsolution':pHvalue_c, 'waterlevel':distance_c, 'CO2 concentration':CO2_c, 'TDS value':tds_c}
result = firebase.put('Region 1', 'Parameter Reading', {'date':date_mmddyyyy,'time':time_hhmmss,'airtemperature':temperature_c,'humidity':humidity_c, 'watertemperature':watertemp_c, 'phsolution':pHvalue_c, 'waterlevel':distance_c, 'CO2 concentration':CO2_c, 'TDS value':tds_c})
result2 = requests.post(firebase_url + '/' + reading_location + '/History/Parameter Reading.json', data=json.dumps(data))     
print 'All parameter records are inserted.\nResult Code = ' + str(result2.status_code) + ',' + result2.text
```

Comment: checking your local machine for connectivity is operating system dependent and also doesn't tell you whether there is a problem past the wifi connection itself. Pinging something on the net is really common, so I'd say yes, this is reasonable. You could thin that up to `socket.gethostbyname("www.google.com")`.

Comment: Why don't you just try to connect to the database, and add a timeout to the database connection and continue if you can't connect.

Comment: I am new to Python language, Is there any guide for this. Thanks @FranciscoCouzo

Answer (score 1):

I've used the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/quickstart/) module for this.

> In the event of a network problem (e.g. DNS failure, refused connection, etc), Requests will raise a ConnectionError exception.

So you could do the following:

```
import requests

def is_connected():
    try:
        r = requests.get("http://google.com", timeout=5)
        return True

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        return False
```

Note that it may raise other exceptions, but this should be enough to start.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @FranciscoCouzo, you can just try the connect and see what happens. But suppose you want a smaller sanity check before even delving into the database portion of your code. If you know the port number of your database server (1433 for instance) you can try a connect and then reset that connection.  You still have to deal with loosing your wifi connection as you work, but this is a light weight way to know its okay to start.

```
import socket
import struct

def is_alive(host, port):
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    try:
        s.settimeout(5)
        s.connect((host, port))
        s.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_LINGER,
            struct.pack("ii", 1, 0))
        s.close()
    except OSError:
        return False
    finally:
        s.close()
    return True

print(is_alive("example.com", 1344))
```